# Unable to run gitlab-runner with docker

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Linux (Ubuntu 22.04) and wanted to run `gitlab-runner` with the following YAMK file locally:

```yaml
image: ubuntu:latest

test:
  script:
    - echo "Hello Gitlab-Runner"
```

When I execute `gitlab-runner exec docker test`, I get the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (11.2.0)
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: Error response from daemon: {"message":"client version 1.18 is too old. Minimum supported API version is 1.24, please upgrade your client to a newer version"} (executor_docker.go:1147:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
```

I checked the docker version I have:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           26.0.0
 API version:       1.45
 Go version:        go1.21.8
 Git commit:        2ae903e
 Built:             Wed Mar 20 15:17:51 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          26.0.0
  API version:      1.45 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.8
  Git commit:       8b79278
  Built:            Wed Mar 20 15:17:51 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.28
  GitCommit:        ae07eda36dd25f8a1b98dfbf587313b99c0190bb
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
  GitCommit:        v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you _absolutely_ sure that you only have a single `docker` version installed and/or running on your system? Don't forget to check for `podman` too.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded the gitlab-runner version to the latest one, and could resolve the issue.
However, it is not clear why the problem occurred with the lower gitlab-runner version.